# How can I make this animation work?

Tags: swift, animation

I was trying to animate a set of images using this tutorial: https://www.geekylemon.com/animated-loading-screen. I  converted the code from objective c to swift in order to implement it into another project, but it seems like it doesn't work properly.
Well, on the the storyboard are three Image Views(AnitmationimageView beeing the same with "L1.png", Loadimageview and the background image of the view controller). I wanted to run the AnitmationimageView and after it a transition to L1,2,3,4 images and after them to Loadimageview and after it to the background image. But when I run the program it only shows me the transition from AnitmationimageView to Loadimageview and the transition from Loadimageview to the background image. Hope this helps in "diagnosing" my problem.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var AnitmationimageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var Loadimageview: UIImageView!
    var loading_1: UIImage!
    var loading_2: UIImage!
    var loading_3: UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        AnitmationimageView.animationImages = [UIImage(named: "L1.png"), UIImage(named: "L2.png"), UIImage(named: "L3.png"), UIImage(named: "L4.png")] as? [UIImage]
        AnitmationimageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
        AnitmationimageView.animationDuration = 3 as CFTimeInterval 
        AnitmationimageView.startAnimating()
        perform(#selector(self.delay1), with: nil, afterDelay: 3)
        delay1()
        delay2()
        delay3()
    }

    @objc func delay1() {
        UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(1.0)
        AnitmationimageView.alpha = 0
        UIView.commitAnimations()
        perform(#selector(self.delay2), with: nil, afterDelay: 1.0)
    }

    @objc func delay2() {
        UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(1.0)
        Loadimageview.alpha = 1
        UIView.commitAnimations()
        perform(#selector(self.delay3), with: nil, afterDelay: 1.5)
    }

    @objc func delay3() {
        UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(1.0)
        Loadimageview.alpha = 0
        UIView.commitAnimations()
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouln't call your animation methods in `viewDidLoad()`. Use `viewDidAppear(:)` instead. You should only call `delay1()` since the delay methods are already chained together.

Comment: FYI - you really should being using the far more up-to-date block/closure based `UIView` animation methods.

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: The words "doesn't work" are the least useful way to describe a problem. Can you please [edit] your question with specific details describing in what way the code doesn't work? Are you getting compiler warnings or errors? Does the code crash? Does it behave differently than expected? Be very clear and specific about the issue.